# c++ sort doesn't use custom function

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, comparator, stl-algorithm

I'm trying to sort

```
std::vector< std::vector< std::string> > perm;
```

I am attempting to use `std::sort` from the algorithm header

I called it with

```
std::sort( perm.begin(), perm.end(), sortPerms);
```

This is my sort function:

```
bool sortPerms (const std::vector<std::string> &i, const std::vector<std::string> &j) {
  for(unsigned int x = 0; x < i.size(); x++) {
    if(i[x] != j[x])
      return false;
  }
  //both are equal
  return true;
}
```

The purpose of sorting is to then call std::unique to obtain a vector with unique values.
When I compile with gcc in cygwin, I get no errors but I have repeats, and when I compile with visual studio 2010, I get an error that operator< is not defined.
I stepped through and it is attempting to use its own sort function, and not the one that I have defined.

I'm not sure how to fix this, any suggestions?

Other details:
It is guaranteed that all vectors will be of same size.
It's purpose is a vector of every permutation of an original vector of strings.
Each string is a command, and I am looking for all of the different ways these commands can be shuffled. So I need to strip the duplicates.

Comment: Can you point to the line in which you have the error, please?

Comment: How do you expect to **sort** something based solely on a concept of being unequal?

Comment: Its an assertion inside of <algorithm> that states that operator< is undefined. I'm not sure why that's an issue if I supplied my own comparator

Comment: I don't see supplied operator but a callback function to std::sort(). I guess on Windows it uses `LEFT < RIGHT`, where `LEFT` is in your case `std::vector< std::string >`. You may need to declare structure with an `operator<` inside that would derive from `std::vector< std::string >` and work through it.

Comment: @Grzegorz: Why a new type that derives `std::vector<std::string>`? Just make a free ("global") `operator<` like sane people! `bool operator<(const std::vector<std::string>& a, const std::vector<std::string>& b);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sort function should return when `a < b`, not `a != b`.

Also, by default, `std::vector<>` should already support lexicographic comparison via `operator<`, which should do what you're expecting (compare each element in turn, with the first non-equivalent elements used for the comparison).   See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp

Your current sortPerms function looks like what you would pass to `std::unique`, but that has different behavior than a predicate used for `std::sort`.

Comment: sweet, thanks.
I wasn't sure if vector would have a function of such, thanks.
Also, I don't think that a < b, comparing the actual commands, would work in this case for grouping like std::vector<std::string>'s together. But I'm aware that's usually how its done.

Thanks again